# Crashlytics BigQuery integration table expiration

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

Is it possible to set the default table expiration that is used when enabling the Crashlytics Big Query integration in Firebase?

We are trying to reduce our monthly Firebase costs (Blaze plan) that are due to the amount of data exported automatically and now exists  in our BigQuery tables. These are the costs that appear in our Firebase billing reports as "non Firebase services".

To reduce the costs we would like to allow the data to expire automatically and adjust the "time to expire" shown below for all ongoing data exported from Firebase to BigQuery.

Is this possible from within the Firebase console itself? Or can this only be done in BigQuery using the CLI? This page doesn’t seem to give any indication that this is possible from the Firebase Console itself: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export

But we can see from the BigQuery docs that Table Expiration appears to be what we need to set, our question is essentially how to do this to apply for all existing and future tables streamed from Firebase Crashlytics (but also Events and Performance) data.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

You can limit data in BigQuery by setting the retention time right in the BigQuery console to whatever length of time you prefer:

- Set default table expiration times [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#table-expiration)
- Update a particular table's expiration time [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time)

The size of exported data highly depends on the product usage. Moreover, especially for Crashlytics, stacktrace in the data is completely unpredictable.
In order for you to have an idea of the cost, You can check following links:

- [Schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484) of the exported table
- [Columns](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#without_stack_traces) presenting regardless of the stack trace
- BigQuery [Free operations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free-tier)

Additionally, please follow following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#understanding_the_firebase_crashlytics_schema_in_bigquery), which has clearer insight on the export data to BigQuery.